# multiprocessing script using Pipes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

When I try to run the following script, process 1 displays just 1 sec of video and get stuck. is there any problem with the code? My goal is to run two processes, one which display's the frames continuously and other process perform face detection and print the results whenever the process1 sets the event. Process 1 sets the event at regular intervals i.e, after every 20 or 30 frames.

```py
def read(e,parent):

    fps,st,frames_to_count,cnt = (0,0,30,0)
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture('sample.mp4')
    wid = 640
    while(vid.isOpened()):
        res,frame = vid.read()
        if not res:
            break
        frame = imutils.resize(frame,width = wid)
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO',frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        if cnt == frames_to_count:
            try:
                fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                parent.send(frame)
                e.set()
                st=time.time()
                cnt=0
            except:
                pass
        cnt+=1
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def fd(e,child):

    face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("path to xml")
    while True:
        e.wait()
        faces=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(child.recv(),1.1,4)
        print(faces)
        e.clear()

def main():

    e = Event()
    (child,parent) = Pipe()
    p1 = Process(target=read, args=(e,parent))
    p2 = Process(target=fd, args=(e,child))
    p1.start() 
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":

  main()
```

Comment: I don't know why need an `Event` at all. You have a possible race condition where `fd` might be clearing the event after `read` has just set it and then `fd` might be waiting on an event that had been set and now cleared. Now the problem is that `read` might not be able to reset the event because it only does so *after* it sends then next frame and it might not be able to do that because of a pipe's limited capacity (why are you using a `Pipe` instead of a `Queue`). Your problem may be the result of over-engineering with using the wrong tools combined with doing operations in the wrong order.

Comment: Just sending the next frame is in itself an "event" that signals to `fd` that a new frame is ready. But if `read` is able to send frames faster than `fd` can process them, it will block because of the limited capacity of a `Pipe` . That could be a good thing, which prevents a `Queue` from growing indefinitely in size, or not depending on your application. But if you are using events, you would need two events.: `fd` would have to have a way of telling `read` that it is through processing (and has done its clear of the first event) and now it is okay for `read` to send the next frame. (more...)

Comment: But far simpler would be just to use a full duplex Pipe instead of events where `read` just sends back its own message signaling that it has processed the frame on which `read` does a `recv` before proceeding. But why is any of this even necessary? `read` should just be doing `send` operations in a loop and `fd` does `recv` operations in a loop. Or use 'put' and `get` with a `Queue` if you want unlimited capacity so as to not block `read` if `fd` cannot keep up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See all my comments to your posted question. In the code below I have retained the `Pipe` that you are using but have specified *duplex=False* since you are not using the returned connections for two-way communication and have correspondingly renamed these connections from `child` and `parent` to the now more meaningful `read_conn` and `send_conn`. I have, of course, removed the `Event` instance.

Since `fd` appears to be in a loop that never terminates, `main` will never be able to `join` that process. Therefore, `p2` should be created as a *daemon* process that will automatically terminate when all non-daemon processes and threads terminate.

```py
def read(send_conn):

    fps,st,frames_to_count,cnt = (0,0,30,0)
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture('sample.mp4')
    wid = 640
    while(vid.isOpened()):
        res,frame = vid.read()
        if not res:
            break
        frame = imutils.resize(frame,width = wid)
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO',frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        if cnt == frames_to_count:
            try:
                fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                send_conn.send(frame)
                st=time.time()
                cnt=0
            except:
                pass
        cnt+=1
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def fd(recv_conn):

    face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("path to xml")
    while True:
        faces=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(recv_conn.recv(),1.1,4)
        print(faces)

def main():

    (recv_conn,send_conn) = Pipe(duplex=False)
    p1 = Process(target=read, args=(send_conn,))
    p2 = Process(target=fd, args=(recv_conn,), daemon=True)
    p1.start() 
    p2.start()
    p1.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Using "event" was redundant. That was silly